# screen -Amds screenname /patch/to/script.sh don't work only on debian

Tags: debian, scripting, gnu-screen

I have a problem with screen software, when I try to start screen with options `screen -Amds screenname /patc/to/script.sh` - nothing happens, it's a problem only on Debian system. On CentOS and FreeBSD - everything is OK (other OS I don't use, and don't know of the problem).

Answer (score 1):

Try `screen -AmdS screenname /path/to/script.sh` - note the capital S.

Comment: I try screen -AmdS screenname /path/to/script.sh and screen -ls says No sockets found in /var/run/screen/S-root, screen don't start.

Comment: How about `screen -AdmS screenname`, then `screen -r screenname`, then running your script? Maybe the script is errorring/finishing quickly.